# Bond a BLE device without createBond()

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating an Android app - one feature of this app is that if the user connects to a BLE device and clicks a button, the app will remember the device and automatically connect in future. From what I understand, this means I need bonding.

I came across the `createBond()` method, but realised that it is only usable in API 19 (Android 4.4) and onwards. The person I am making this for would much prefer it be available in API 18 (Android 4.3) as the product has already been advertised as such.

Assuming that I am correct in my approach (meaning, through active use of Bonding - I'm self-teaching Bluetooth, so please correct me if this isn't the way to go or if I am misunderstanding), is there any way that I can achieve what I want to without `createBond()`? If so, how? Or is API19 something we will have to live with?

Comment: Once you've connected to your device, you can store the device's address (`BluetoothDevice.getAddress()`) in a preference somewhere. Then on your listener for scanning for devices, as soon as a device matches that address, initiate your connection as normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a preference in conjunction with your callback for device scanning.

Assuming you're using an `LeScanCallback` somewhere in your app:

```
BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mCallBack =
    new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
         // You can place this elsewhere so this isn't called for every device
         String storedAddr = myContext.getSharedPreferences("global", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("storedAddr","");

         if(storedAddr.equals("")) {
             // Do your normal process to list / connect to devices.
             // Store device.getAddress() in preferences once connected.

         } else if(device.getAddress().equals(storedAddr) {
             // Do whatever you want with the matching device
         }

        }

}
```

Of course, you'll have to deal with an option to remove that stored address so that they can choose a new device to save, if needed.